# Javascript Regex for the String to replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like,

```
(Range:(>"A" OR Range:(>"B" OR Range:(>"AB")
```

I need to convert it like,

```
(Range:(>"A") OR Range:(>"B") OR Range:(>"AB"))
```

please help me out how to identify it with regex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: More info, please. Currently, a simple string search/replace would be sufficient. What is the *pattern*  you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
(\(>"[^"]*")
```

and replace with

```
$1)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2untd)

It searches for `(>"` followed by anything but quotes and the closing quote. this is stored in `$1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot stema. That saves my time

Answer (score 1):

Replace the pattern:

```
/("[^"]*")/g
```

with:

```
$1)
```

Here's a demo on Ideone: http://ideone.com/BfYBK

Comment: Thanks a lot Bart. That saves my time